# current location and path tracing requirements issue

Tags: iphone, dictionary, path, gps, tracking

i am doing GPS based application with the functionality of showing current location and with walking moving it should show the path tracing at stop command gives the distance .(i go through apple documentation but not getting clearly many things .)
what i have done
i have added map view, showing current location .

need to be done .
Should i required the GeoJSON file for showing sub way path on the map .advice me in best way and please give me step flow to achieve this .

thank you in advance .

Answer (score 0):

Check out the breadcrumb sample code from apple which shows how to do this- http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/Breadcrumb/Introduction/Intro.html

The GeoJSON file is only for integrating with apple maps app.

Comment: please illustrate ,what do you mean by apple maps app, i am also using map to show location so its also the apple map apps.

Comment: Yes, this will allow for GPS tracking.  Follow the code in the sample project.  The GeoJSON file is a coverage file which allows your app to provide routing directions to the official apple maps app.